# How to restrict all other paths except one for Universal link in iOS to open app using URL

Tags: ios, ios9, deep-linking

I am using Unviversal link in iOS application.
I am referring Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

I want to open app for only one path. example domain is https://example.com and paths are /a, /b, and so on. I want to give access to only '/b' path. 
How do I do it?

Comment: did you try this https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection

Comment: I am able to launch the application using URL. I want to know how to add restriction for sub paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Links operate on an opt-in basis for URLs. In other words, if you don't explicitly specify a path in the `apple-app-site-association` file (either by literal string or wildcard matching), it won't be used.

Using Apple's example as a basis:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/b"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify an area that should not be handled by adding “NOT ” (including a space after the T) to the beginning of the path string. For example, you Want to  prevent to handle the /videos/samples/2010/* area of the website then the paths array as shown here:

```
"paths": [ "/videos/collections/*", "NOT /videos/samples/2010/*", "/videos/samples/201?/*"]
```